# AWS consolidated billing on reserved instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

My AWS infrastructure is part of consolidated billing provided by our client company.
There may be other accounts for different companies and are part of consolidated billing.

So, when I reserve an instance, do all other accounts within the consolidated billing umbrella enjoy the privileges?

Does it make sense to have reserved instances in consolidated billing environment if you don't want to share the benefits with other accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when you use consolidated billing the cost-savings of a reserved instance can be spread/shared to any of the 'child' accounts - just like the savings you may get by combing your total S3 storage (for example).

Comment: Brennan So does it make sense to have reserved instances in consolidated billing environment if you don't want to share the benefits with other accounts?

Comment: Your bill will be higher if you use an instance 24x7x365 and don't reserve an instance, so yes ,there is an advantage to paying for a reserved instance - at least as far as the person paying the bill is concerned.

Comment: Okay. Makes sense.
Thank you.

Comment: The savings from the reserved instance, for a particular sub-account, will be lower in that the savings is spread across all of the sub-accounts: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-ri-consolidated-billing/